# BinaryReader ReadString specifying length?

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I'm working on a parser to receive UDP information, parse it, and store it. To do so I'm using a `BinaryReader` since it will mostly be binary information. Some of it will be strings though. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring.aspx) for the `ReadString()` function:

> Reads a string from the current stream. The string is prefixed with
>   the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time.

And I completely understand it up until "seven bits at a time" which I tried to simply ignore until I started testing. I'm creating my own byte array before putting it into a `MemoryStream` and attempting to read it with a `BinaryReader`. Here's what I first thought would work:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 3, 0, 0, 0, (byte)'C', (byte)'a', (byte)'t', }
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));
String str = reader.ReadString();
```

Knowing an `int` is 4 bytes (and toying around long enough to find out that `BinaryReader` is Little Endian) I pass it the length of 3 and the corresponding letters. However `str` ends up holding `\0\0\0`. If I remove the 3 zeros and just have

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 3, (byte)'C', (byte)'a', (byte)'t', }
```

Then it reads and stores `Cat` properly. To me this conflicts with the documentation saying that the length is supposed to be an integer. Now I'm beginning to think they simply mean a number with no decimal place and not the data type `int`. Does this mean that a `BinaryReader` can never read a string larger than 127 characters (since that would be 01111111 corresponding to the 7 bits part of the documentation)?

I'm writing up a protocol and need to completely understand what I'm getting into before I pass our documentation along to our clients.

Comment: BinaryReader is designed to read things in that were written out with BinaryWriter. So try writing out different length strings with a BinaryWriter and you should be able to figure out the protocol.

Comment: But you'd better find out how that UDP protocol sends you the data, when it doesn't prefix the string (and that's  the most likely)   this is all in vain.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd946975%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: I'm defining the protocol for my work and the code that's sending the data will most likely not be written in C# (probably python or C on linux) and thus won't have access to BinaryWriter. I'm using BinaryReader for code readability although I may ditch `ReadString` and use a solid 4 bytes for length and use `ReadChars` so it's easier to implement.

Comment: I was wrong about the Encoding, it uses the "Writers current encoding".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/BinaryReader@cs/1305376/BinaryReader@cs) for `BinaryReader`. It uses a function called [Read7BitEncodedInt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.read7bitencodedint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and after looking up that documentation and the documentation for [Write7BitEncodedInt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I found this:

> The integer of the value parameter is written out seven bits at a
>   time, starting with the seven least-significant bits. The high bit of
>   a byte indicates whether there are more bytes to be written after this
>   one. If value will fit in seven bits, it takes only one byte of space.
>   If value will not fit in seven bits, the high bit is set on the first
>   byte and written out. value is then shifted by seven bits and the next
>   byte is written. This process is repeated until the entire integer has
>   been written.

Also, Ralf found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd946975%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that better displays what's going on.

Comment: But what if the binary stream was written by a program running on a Big Endian machine and then read (for example if the file is transported) by another program on a Little Endian machine? I think they missed that. I am writing an application where I write the streams in Big Endian (Network Byte Order).

Answer (score 2):

Unless they specifically say 'int' or 'Int32', they just mean an integer as in a whole number.

By '7 bits at time', they mean that it implements 7-bit length encoding, which seems a bit confusing at first but is actually rather straightforward. Here are some example values and how they are written out using 7-bit length encoding:

```
/*
decimal value   binary value                ->  enc byte 1   enc byte 2   enc byte 3
85              00000000 00000000 01010101  ->  01010101     n/a          n/a
1,365           00000000 00000101 01010101  ->  11010101     00001010     n/a
349,525         00000101 01010101 01010101  ->  11010101     10101010     00010101
*/
```

The table above uses big endian for no other reason than I simply had to pick one and it's what I'm most familiar with. The way 7-bit length encoding works, it is little endian by it's very nature.

Note that 85 writes out to 1 byte, 1,365 writes out to 2 bytes, and 349,525 writes out to 3 bytes.

Here's the same table using letters to show how each value's bits were used in the written output (dashes are zero-value bits, and the 0s and 1s are what's added by the encoding mechanism to indicate if a subsequent byte is to be written/read)...

```
/*
decimal value   binary value                ->  enc byte 1   enc byte 2   enc byte 3
85              -------- -------- -AAAAAAA  ->  0AAAAAAA     n/a          n/a
1,365           -------- -----BBB AAAAAAAA  ->  1AAAAAAA     0---BBBA     n/a
349,525         -----CCC BBBBBBBB AAAAAAAA  ->  1AAAAAAA     1BBBBBBA     0--CCCBB
*/
```

So values in the range of 0 to 2^7-1 (127) will write out as 1 byte, values of 2^7 (128) to 2^14-1 (16,383) will use 2 bytes, 2^14 (16,384) to 2^21-1 (2,097,151) will take 3 bytes, and so on and so forth.