# Sending String from Java to .NET BinaryReader.ReadString

Tags: java

I want to send a TCPMessage from my Java TCP-Client to my Visual Basic server.

The server uses the BinaryReader.ReadString() function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring.aspx

The ReadString function expects a 7bit-length prefix of the size of the string.

Currently this is my code, but the server doesn't recognize the message.

```
public void sendMessage(String message) { 
     if (out != null &&  !out.checkError()) {
         out.print(message.length());
         out.println(message);
         out.flush(); 
     } 
 }
```

And I can't change the whole server architecture to make it recognize the string e.g. From ReadLine.

Hope that somebody can help, trying it now for hours.

Comment: You can't just use Java's binary serialization with .NET, that's the main problem I'm seeing with what you have in mind. Is there any reason you're trying to to use a BinaryReader?

Comment: It's an async server sample which can handle disconnected clients.

I always had problems on my own server with handling disconnects or reconnects, it always crashed.

But this sample i found works and now i already added some more code, which is the reason why i don't want to start from scratch again.

And the person i got the sample from was using the binary reader to manage it.

I already fixed the problem to send data from java client to VB-server.

Now im trying to figure out how to evade using the bufferedreader.readline method to receive data from VB-server.

For more see comments below

Comment: I am afraid your interpretation of the .net documentation is wrong. See this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19710688/697630).

Answer (score 0):

Your `out` is probably a `PrintWriter`, which translates data to text. For instance, `out.print()` writes the value's length as a string, while `ReadString` reads the string's length as binary data. For starters, you need to change `out` to an `OutputStream` (which writes binary data) rather than a `PrintWriter`. Another thing is that you need to make sure the character encoding of the string written by Java matches the encoding used by BinaryReader (the default is UTF-8). Note also that ReadString expects the string's length to be encoded in a special format as described in the [Write7BitEncodedInt method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint.aspx).

Finally, ReadString doesn't expect a line break to appear at the end of the string (`println` implicitly adds a line break).

Comment: Ah okay, i really appreciate your help mate!
I did it now by using the write function 2 times.
First: writing the length of the message
Second: writing the message itself

Now i have one last issue:
When im sending data from my VB-Server, it has to end with the .NET Constant vbCrlf (\n) in Java.

How can i manage to do it without vbCrlf?
The problem is that i need to distinguish the different clients, to send java clients the + Vbcrlf and normal VB clients the message only.

Comment: So far i tried it like this, but nothing seems to be received :/.
         int value=0;
         
         // reads to the end of the stream 
         while((value = br.read()) != -1)
         {
            // converts int to character
            char c = (char)value;
            
            // prints character
            System.out.println(c);
         }

Comment: I have edited my answer. By the way, the code you just gave just reads data from Java.  I thought you were intending to only send data from Java?

Comment: It's sending the data to VB TCP-Server.

Now i need to figure out to receive data from the server without using the readline method, cuz in this case i always need to send vbCrlf from VB to make the Java Client recognize the answer.

See previous post how i tried to receive data without using Readline.

Btw. "in" is a BufferedReader.

Comment: That's a new question that you didn't ask in this page.  You should post a new question using the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page.

Comment: Okay, i'll do :). Thanks anyways!!